# Correct notation for field of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

What is the correct notation for Boolean algebra is that defined by the power set (set of all subsets) of set {a,b} 
$$
(\{0,a,b,1 \}, C, \cap ,\cup, 0, 1)
$$
or
$$
(\{a,b\}, C, \cap ,\cup, 0, 1)
$$
and what is the carrier set for this algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your own specification the carrier set is the power set $\mathcal P(\{a,b\})$ which is $\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

So the algebra would be something like
$$ (\mathcal P(\{a,b\}), (A\mapsto\{a,b\}\setminus A), \cap, \cup, \varnothing, \{a,b\} ) $$